# I don't understand, a Javascript object that lives in another object has their own live?

Tags: javascript, oop

So I write simple code, it's about domino card game
the code :

```
var Card = function(head, tail) {
    this.head = head;
    this.tail = tail;
}

Card.prototype.init = function() {
  var res = [];
   function head(num1) {

    if(num1 < 0 ) return res;
    function tail(num2) {

    if(num2 < 0 ) {return head(num1 - 1)};
    if(num1 < num2) {return tail(num2 - 1)};
    res.push(new Card(num1,num2));   
    return tail(num2 - 1);

    }
    return tail(6);

  }
  return head(6);
}

var Dealer = function(sets) {
  this.sets = [];
}

Dealer.prototype.shuffle = function(arr) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = arr.length; i; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        x = arr[i - 1];
        arr[i - 1] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = x;
    }
    return arr;
}

Dealer.prototype.chunk = function(arr) {
    var res =[], chunks, i = 0;
    chunks = arr.length / 7;

    while(i < chunks){
      //debugger;
        res[i] = arr.splice(0,7);
    i++;
    }
    this.sets = res;
}

Dealer.prototype.share = function(table) {                           
  this.sets.forEach(function(value, index) {
    table.chairs[index].cardSet = value;
  });
}

var Player = function(name, cardSet) {                        
  this.name = name;
}




////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var Table = function(id, chairs) {                                  
  this.id = id;
  this.chairs = [];
}

Table.prototype.seatForPlayer = function(player) {
  this.chairs.push(player);
}

Table.prototype.isFull = function() {                               // TO DO WITH PROTOTYPE
  return (this.chairs.length == 4) ? true : false;
}

//define table
var table = new Table(1);

//define player
var kuyi = new Player("kuyi");
var kuya = new Player("kuya");
var chuck = new Player("chuck");
var noris = new Player("noris");

//initialized cards
var cards = new Card().init();
var dealer = new Dealer();


table.seatForPlayer(kuyi)
table.seatForPlayer(kuya)
table.seatForPlayer(chuck)
table.seatForPlayer(noris)


dealer.shuffle(cards);
dealer.chunk(cards);
dealer.share(table);

console.log(table);
console.log("player kuya: ", kuya);
```

my question is why when i'm logging player out it have cardSet array, I'm surprized because I think player that have cardSet only lives in table object, and why is that?

Comment: Could you cut down on the code and keep only the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: `table.chairs[index].cardSet = value;` you are setting the cards on the player object then.

Comment: come on why I got -2, please be easy on me I'm just a beginner

Answer (score 0):

When you call the Share function on the Dealer object, it adds the cardSet property on each index of the chair, which happens to be the players.

```
Dealer.prototype.share = function(table) {                           
  this.sets.forEach(function(value, index) {
      table.chairs[index].cardSet = value;
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying, I know that I'm assigning cardSet inside the table object, but I think the cardSet property is only live in table object not in the player object.

Comment: Your `table` object is an array containing `player` objects. When you set it for each thing in `table`, you are modifying the players directly.